# How to put footnotes in two columns?

Tags: packages, footnotes, texmaker, two-column

I´m learning LaTex and need write an article in Texmaker, but I have a problem
someone know how can I put on the following footnote style?
I mean, need put the footnotes in two colums :c

[image: footnote twocolums style]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on which class you are using. Here a suggestion in memoir class:
see also [memoir manual](https://ftp.kddilabs.jp/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) page 237.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{memoir}
\twocolumnfootnotes

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    
    \lipsum[2]
    \footnote{Here is some text as a footnote-Here is some text as a footnote-Here is some text as a footnote-Here is some text as a footnote-Here is some text as a footnote}
    \lipsum[2]
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As you show two columns in main text, just do not mess up what `article` does by default.

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for type dummy text
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]\footnote{\lipsum[8][1-8]}
\lipsum[4-5]\footnote{\lipsum[9][1-8]}
\lipsum[6-7]    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a multicol version.

Normally `\footins` is filled using `\insert`.  This fills `\footcolumn` and replaces `\footins` with a two column version each time.

The problem with this approach is that footnotes in the first paragraph on a page may appear on the previous page.  This can be manually corrected with `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newsavebox{\footcolumn}
\makeatletter
\long\def\@footnotetext#1{%
  \global\setbox\footcolumn=\vbox{%
  \hsize=\dimexpr \textwidth+\columnsep-\col@number\columnsep\relax
  \divide\hsize by \col@number
  \unvbox\footcolumn
  \reset@font\footnotesize
  \interlinepenalty\interfootnotelinepenalty
  \splittopskip\footnotesep
  \splitmaxdepth \dp\strutbox \floatingpenalty \@MM
  \@parboxrestore
  \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\csname p@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark}%
  \color@begingroup
  \@makefntext{%
  \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces#1\@finalstrut\strutbox}%
  \par
  \color@endgroup}% \footcolumn ready
  \bgroup
  \c@finalcolumnbadness=0
  \setbox0=\copy\footcolumn
  \global\setbox\footins=\vbox{\noindent\begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}
    \begin{multicols}{\col@number}
    \unvbox0
    \end{multicols}%
    \end{minipage}}% \footins ready
  \egroup}
\makeatother

\AddToHook{shipout/after}{\sbox0{\box\footcolumn}}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \lipsum[2]
    \footnote{Here is some text as a footnote-Here is some text as a footnote-Here is some text as a footnote-Here is some text as a footnote-Here is some text as a footnote}
    \lipsum[2]
    \footnote{A second footnote}
    \lipsum[1-6]\footnote{Next page.}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello guys, thank you all for your advices and examples, really helped me.

Comment: You will need to repeat that after every answer to make sure they get the message.  You can also use @name, but only one name per message.  Also, thanks are considered redundant here.  Use the up markers so show appreciation.

Comment: This is a great answer the only problem I had was that footnotes where never cleared meaning that a footnote placed in a given page will be repeated in all subsequent pages containing footnotes. This seems reasonable considering that your code appends to `footcolumn`, copies `footcolumn` but never clears it. Inserting `\usepackage{everyshi}\EveryShipout{\global\setbox\footcolumn=\vbox{}}` fixes the problem by clearing `footcolumn` just before shipping the page.

Comment: @HomoVafer - Thanks.