# Vertical, centred footnotes?

Tags: footnotes

Is there a way to replicate in LaTeX these 'traditional' (19th century) British footnotes, which are 1) first vertically stacked, then horizontally added and 2) centred on the page, with 3) the annoying extra (accurate to old texts) that the vertical 'stacking' commences *only* when the number of footnotes >2?

[image: footies]

[image: footies more]

[image: footies more]

Comment: The `yafoot`  bundle has a `dblfnote`  package that enables two-column footnotes.

Comment: You could do it manually using a bottom float.  If you knew the maxi,um width, you could do it.  Footnotes are formatted as they are created.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/610119/how-to-put-footnotes-in-two-columns

Comment: Is it also required that the numbering of footnotes starts with (1) again on every page? The examples suggest that, and it would add additional complexity.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen Regrettably, yes it is

Comment: I learned that `footmisc` achieves per-page footnotes by making two passes. This package would have to be extended with alignment and stacking following the ideas laid out in the footnotes example in appendix D of The TeXbook.

Comment: If you placed an upper limit on the number of footnotes per page, you could put each footnote into a separate savebox.

Comment: @bookplatelover How shall it look for 3, 5 or 6 footnotes on a given page?

Comment: You would have to count them anyway to assign them to different boxes.

Comment: If you completely replaced \footins each time you added a footnote (instead of using \insert) it would reserve the correct amount of space at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: According to the TeX program §1009, the height of the `\footins` box is subtracted from the page goal only once per page, when the first `\insert\footins` occurs. If we don't use `\insert` at all, nothing will be reserved, right?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen - I've used `\global\setbox\footins=\vbox{...}` many times with no problems regarding page size. (The problems involve getting the footnotes in the right order and on the right page.)  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314375/why-does-parbox-lose-footnotes for example.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: `\def\s{\hrule height10cm width10cm}\null\s\penalty0 \s\setbox\footins=\vbox{\s}\insert\footins{}\bye` places one `\s` on the first page and one on the second, with enough space for the footnote. But without the `\insert\footins{}`, it gives one overfull page.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen - I just ran the first solution from the linked question and it worked fine, no errors, no warnings.  I added \blindtext[4] and all the footnotes were still on the first page.

Comment: Perhaps there is a difference between plain TeX and LaTeX? If `\s` is a blindtext that takes up 40% of the page, then `\s\setbox\footins=\vbox{\s}\insert\footins{}\s\bye` gives two pages with enough room for the footnote on the first, but without the `\insert\footins{}`, it gives one overfull page.

Answer (score 2):

The `memoir` class goes some way to do this, but in general I think that manual intervention will need to be applied unless some LaTeX supremo can come up with something. However the application might be so limited that they might feel that it is not worth their time although perhaps someone would treat this as an intellectual exercise.

Basically you are asking for two styles of footnotes. If only one on a page then it should be centered. If more, then set in two columns, centered.

```
% oefootnotesprob.tex  SE 622546

\documentclass{memoir}
\setlength{\textheight}{0.33\textheight} % just to shorten the pages

\usepackage{lipsum}

%% make footnotes start at 1 on each page
\usepackage{perpage}
\MakePerPage{footnote}

\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{}  %% no rule above footnotes
 
\begin{document}

%%% footnotes set in two twolumns, non centered
\twocolumnfootnotes
\footmarkstyle{(#1) }  % marker in footnote set in parentheses
\lipsum[1]%
\footnote{One}\footnote{Two}\footnote{Three}

\newpage

%%%%% just one (centered) footnote on this page
\plainfootnotes
\setlength{\footmarkwidth}{0em}
\footmarkstyle{\hfil (#1) }
\lipsum[2]\footnote{Another \hfil}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

The MWE showed a centered single footnote and footnotes in two columns which were not centered. I don't know how to automate these, nor how to center the two columns.

Another thought. What if a footnote on one page overflows to the following page which has a different format (multiple versus singe)?

Answer (score 0):

Taking together the ideas from the discussion, I came up with the following case-by-case implementation for up to 4 footnotes:

```tex
\newcount\footcount
\def\stackfootnotes#1{\tabskip1em plus 1fil\halign to\hsize{&\hfil##\hfil\cr #1}}
\def\footnote#1{\advance\footcount by1 \toks\footcount={#1}
  \ifdim\pagegoal<\maxdimen
    \dimen0=\pagegoal \advance\dimen0 by-\ht\footins
    \advance\dimen0 by-\dp\footins \pagegoal=\dimen0\fi
  \setbox\footins=\vbox{\ifcase\footcount \or
  \stackfootnotes{\the\toks1 \cr}\or
  \stackfootnotes{\the\toks1 &\the\toks2 \cr}\or
  \stackfootnotes{\the\toks1 &\the\toks2 \cr\multispan2\hfil\the\toks3 \hfil\cr}\or
  \stackfootnotes{\the\toks1 &\the\toks3 \cr\the\toks2 &\the\toks4 \cr}\fi}
  \ifdim\pagegoal<\maxdimen
    \dimen0=\pagegoal \advance\dimen0 by\ht\footins
    \advance\dimen0 by\dp\footins \pagegoal=\dimen0\fi}
```

It's laborious, but easy to adapt. `\footcount` must be reset to 0 on every page.

**Dangerous bend:** The `\pagegoal` manipulations are meant to reserve space for the footnotes box at the bottom of the page. TeX would do this automatically if we used `\insert\footins`, but we manipulate `\box\footins` directly instead. (See also my comment to the question.)