# \setbox\footins instead of \insert\footins?

Tags: footnotes

This question arised out of a comment to [Vertical, centred footnotes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/622546)

That question dealt with advanced formatting of footnotes and a solution was suggested where every footnote *replaces* the entire box using `\setbox\footins=\vbox{...}` box rather than add to it using `\insert\footins{...}`. Are there LaTeX packages that use this practice?

I ask because according to the TeX program §1009, the height of the `\footins` box is subtracted from the page goal only once per page, when the first `\insert\footins` occurs. Without any `\insert\footins`, no space will be reserved for the footnotes, which can lead to an overfull page as in this example:

```tex
\def\s{\count0=0\loop\line{Lorem ipsum\hfil}\advance\count0 by1
  \ifnum\count0<25\repeat} %blind text taking up 40% of the page
\s\setbox\footins=\vbox{\s}
%\insert\footins{}
\s\bye
```

Only when the `\insert\footins{}` is present, does this give two pages with enough room for the footnote on the first.

Comment: eg `footmisc` package has things like `\global\setbox\footins\vbox{\FN@makefootnoteparagraph}%` but this is inside the output routine where essentially `\footins` is a normal box, outside the output routine I don't think it's safe to mix `\insert` and `\setbox` on the same box (well safe but not sure it results in a good outcome). Of course you could do as latex does for floats and abandon `\insert` entirely, just use a normal box allocation, and manage page goal by hand,