# How to make a spanned footnote in twocolumn latex document

Tags: pdftex, xetex, luatex

```
\documentclass [11pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{abstract}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author[1]{The first author\footnote{Corresponding Author: The author would like to thank someone The author would like to thank someone .}}
\author[2]{Author2}
\affil[1]{Affiliation One}
\affil[2]{Affiliation Two}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.\footnote{The first footnote.
The first footnote. The first footnote.
The first footnote.The first footnote.
The first footnote.}
 Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede.
The author would like to thank someone The author would like to thank someone.
vamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique 
neque.\footnote{The secont footnote. The author would like to thank someone The author would like to thank someone}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.\footnote{The first footnote.
The first footnote. The first footnote.
The first footnote.The first footnote.
The first footnote.}
 Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede.
The author would like to thank someone The author would like to thank someone.
vamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique 
neque.\footnote{The secont footnote. The author would like to thank someone The author would like to thank someone}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why did you roll-back the code formatting? The missing line breaks of the plain text make your code very unpleasant to read.

Comment: Please, don't remove the code formatting and add precisely what you want to achieve in the question, not just in the title.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "spanned footnote."  If a footnote is too large to fit to the on page where it is created, it will span two columns, but LaTeX tries to avoid that.  If you want to move one of more footnotes to the second column, one can use separate \footnotemark and \footnotetext{...}, although for more than one you might need to use \label and \ref to pass the footnote number.  If you want balanced foornotes, you might combine multicol and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/610119/how-to-put-footnotes-in-two-columns