Multicolumn footnote over multiple pages
I'm digitalizing a book from the 18th century which contains some very large footnotes which spread over multiple pages. This works very well. But now I need to add a very long footnote (long list) which requires a two-column layout.
Problem: This two-column footnote makes no page-break. It just overflows the page.
How can I get a very long two-column footnote?

MWE:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum%
\footnote{%
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \lipsum[1-20]
    \end{multicols}
}
\end{document}


AFAIK memoir supports two-column footnotes with page breaks in a one-column document → https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/610121/277964. Package dblfnote is often used for two-column footnotes in single-column document, but AFAIK does not work in your case. In a twocolumn document on the other hand, two-column footnotes would work out of the box.

@cabohah, thanks for this hint. I gave it a try and it works with memoir. But my book has already about 400 pages and I'm using scrbook as document class. So I expect I can't just replace scrbook by memoir

You can fake it by manually dividing the footnote into page sized chunks.  Interestingly, I could never align the footnote with the footnotemark.  It would stay too low then jump too high.
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}% check margins

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

test\footnote{\vspace*{-2.2\baselineskip}%
  \begin{multicols}{2}
        \indent~
        \lipsum[1-4]
  \end{multicols}
  
  \begin{multicols}{2}
        \lipsum[5-8]
  \end{multicols}
  
  \begin{multicols}{2}
        \lipsum[9-12]
  \end{multicols}
    
  \begin{multicols}{2}
        \lipsum[13-16]
  \end{multicols}
 
  \begin{multicols}{2}
        \lipsum[17-20]
  \end{multicols}
}

\lipsum[2-20]
\end{document}


Thanks, this works indeed in my case. Thanks for this solution
