Two Column Body Text and Two Column Footnotes That Break Across Pages
I want to typeset a document that has the main text in two columns and the footnote text in two columns. If you're in the legal field, Westlaw's reporters typeset court opinions this way.
One can use multicol and dblfnote. However, the footnote text and footnote marker are often placed on separate pages (the command \setcounter{collectmore}{-1} reduces this problem but it still occurs, necessitating manual insertion of page breaks). More generally, dblfnote will not split footnote text across multiple pages which is what causes many of the attendant problems.
In the memoir class, one can use the command \twocolumnfootnotes which typesets the footnotes almost perfectly (the text isn't justified). But, \twocolumnfootnotes used in conjuction with multicol or memoir's twocolumn command doesn't work resulting in each footnote column being the equivalent of a quarter of the total text width.
I have also seen answers on here to use reledmac to achieve this result. Testing this, the following commands will get two column footnotes that are arranged correctly and will split across pages:
\usepackage{reledmac}
\arrangementX[A]{twocol}
\colalignX{\justifying}
\hsizetwocolX[A]{\hsize}
\let\footnote\footnoteA %because document body uses command \footnote

However, this solution in combination with multicol will result in the text of the footnote being below the bottom margin of the page and around the page number. This can be seen if you compile the document below:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum, reledmac, multicol, microtype}

\arrangementX[A]{twocol}
\colalignX{\justifying}
\hsizetwocolX[A]{\hsize}
\let\footnote\footnoteA

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1]\footnote{\lipsum[2]}
\lipsum[3-10]

\end{multicols}
\end{document}

Also, text will overlap if you use reledmac in conjunction with a ``twocolumn``` document.
So my question is whether \twocolumnfootnotes can be modified to extend across the entire text width for a multicol environment. Or, if reledmac can be modified so that the footnotes don't get pushed down below the bottom margin by body text. Or if there is some other solution I'm missing here.

Is there a reason why you can't just use [twocolumn]?

@JohnKormylo I can, but I want the footnotes at the bottom of the page to be balanced. twocolumn won't do that

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/610119/how-to-put-footnotes-in-two-columns/610195?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C37.2090#610195

@JohnKormylo Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried that, but it also won't break footnotes across pages and will still leave footnote text on the wrong page.

Not splitting footnotes across pages seems to be part of multicols, since it knows how much space is needed before if breaks the page.  This also means sometimes pushing a footnote mark to the next page.
